# CSS no longer works after I precompiled?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

My Bootstrap CSS is no longer working correctly after running `RAILS_ENV=production rails assets:precompile`. CSS class names such as bg-dark, text-white still work, but the layout doesnt.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you. I am using Rails 6

Here is an example:

[image: ru]

Comment: what errors are you getting in browser console? any assets not found?

Comment: Nope :/ All assets seem to be found. It worked fine, up until i used ```rails assets:precompile```

Comment: Where do you deploy your app?